# Draw shapes or images on a curved path

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, vector-graphics

I am looking for a drawing library or code examples to draw images or vector shapes repeated along a path which could be curved.

I found a cocoa library which is what I am looking for http://apptree.net/drawkitmain.htm but for .NET.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Scalable Vector Graphics](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/) (SVG). This is ideal for manipulating vectorial images. You may want to look at
[SvgNet](http://www.jbrowse.com/svgnet/).

Answer (score 0):

Or use native .Net in form of WPF. Using a DrawingBrush you can project whatever you like over any vector path you design.